# Solution of $n$th degree equation

Tags: polynomials

The equation $x^n - nqx + (n -1) r= 0$ ($q,r$ belongs to $\Bbb{R}$) has a pair of equal roots. Then how to find relation between $q$ and $r$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried. The answer is $$ q^n = r^{n-1} $$

Comment: Don't discourage anyone by voting down. And thanks for hint

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** A multiple root of $f(x)$ is also a root of $f'(x)$.